# Driver bug in CH340 USB to RS232 converter chip

Tags: usb, rs232

I have a USB to RS232 converter adapter with the chinese chip CH340 from WinChipHead ([wch.cn](http://wch.cn))

[image: CH340 USB to RS232 adapter]

The CH340 chip is not only used in adapter cables. It can also be found in counterfeit **Arduino**'s from China.

1.) I found a bug in that this adapter sometimes sends corrupted data.

2.) Apart from that my driver for the CH340 also has a bug.

What really suprises me is that I cannot find any webpage talking about these bugs although the CH340 is a very widely used chip. Can others confirm these bugs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.)**
The driver which I used (version 3.4) created a **bluescreen** when my computer went to sleep mode or when shutting down while the USB to RS232 adapter was connected.

I found out that there is a newer driver (version 3.5) which is WHQL certified and which fixes this bug.

**2.)**
The second problem is more severe. It happens from time to time that I send a byte **0xFA** but on the cable appears a byte **0x00** instead. I confirmed that on the oscilloscope. Sometimes also other bytes get crippled, but mainly it is 0xFA.

**3.)**
The third bug is that whenever you transmit single bytes the speed is 10 times slower than sending the same amount of bytes in a packet. This is probably a bug in the driver which has a timeout waiting for more data. This bug is in all versions of the driver.

I investigated that and it happens much more frequently when I send a byte 0xFA alone then when I send it in a packet between other bytes.

I tested all my CH340 adapters and found 4 which have the same bug. But I also found one which does not have this bug. I studied them to check if there is any difference between them, and in deed there is. Using the tool [UsbLyzer](https://www.usblyzer.com/) I analyzed the USB descriptor and I found the following difference in the device descriptors:

[image: CH340 device descriptor USB]

The vendor ID 1A86 is **QinHeng Electronics** which seems to be the same company as WinChipHead.

As you see the working adapter has firmware version 2.63 while the defective adapter has firmware version 2.54. This means that they meanwhile have fixed the bug.

I'am software developer and discovered this problem while I was writing my program **HUD ECU Hacker** which uses a USB to RS232 adapter. HUD ECU Hacker is an OBD software (vehicle scanner).

I need that the users of my software can test their adapter to know if it is buggy or not. Therefore I implemented an **Echo Test** into my program. To execute the test the user must connect the RxD and TxD pins of the RS232 adapter so all sent bytes are echoed back to the computer. This echo test also measures the speed of transmission.

Here you see the results of the buggy and the working adapter:

[image: CH340 Echo Test]

My program sends one packet as entire byte block, then the next packet byte by byte. Therefore you see that one sent line (blue) is OK and the next line has errors.

If you have a CH340 adapter and want to test if it is working correctly you can download HUD ECU Hacker [here](https://netcult.ch/elmue/hud%20ecu%20hacker/#Echo_Test).

To execute the test, connect RxD and TxD on the RS232 adapter, select the COM port, set the following configuration and click "Connect":

[image: HUD ECU Hacker Echo Test]

You can also install the fixed WinChipHead driver version 3.5 with my program by clicking on the toolbar above.

[image: Install CH340 driver version 3.5]

Comment: I also have and USB to RJ45 console cable which is listed in the OS as ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter and I could not make it work. When I connect to the serial console I cannot type anything (console is frozen). When I checked the USB information I see that it says also version 2.54 
  idVendor           0x1a86 QinHeng Electronics
  idProduct          0x7523 CH340 serial converter
  bcdDevice            2.54
This is the cable I have https://www.aliexpress.com/item/4000274169804.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.307e4c4d8xq9oe 
This means it is broken ?

Comment: A console software which freezes is low quality software. It should show an error rather than freezing. If you have read my description you know that only some bytes 0xFA are transmitted wrongly. Apart from that the chip works mostly correct. If yours does not work at all, there is another problem. Check the baudrate and handshake settings in your terminal software. And connect the TX and RX wire and make the Echo Test with my HUD ECU Hacker. The console normally sends only ASCII characters. A console software will rarely ever send an 0xFA character. So surely you have another problem.